# How to pass a string method in a map call?

Tags: ruby

I want to write this `["foo", "bar"].map {|x| x.capitalize}` as something like this `["foo", "bar"].map(&method(:String.capitalize))`

To be more precise, given a list `L` of instances of `C` and an instance method `M` I want to call `M` on each element of `L` as `element.M`, in a point-free maner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is `["foo", "bar"].map(&:capitalize)`.

### How does this work?

`:capitalize` is a just a plain ol' ruby symbol.  The magic item here is the ampersand which can be used as a prefix to a method argument; the `&` automatically invokes `to_proc` on the item that it prefixes:

```
x = test(&Bar) # call Bar.to_proc
```

To put it all together, the implementation of `to_proc` on `Symbol` returns a proc that invokes the method with the given name; something like:

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    Proc.new { |object, *args| object.public_send(self, *args) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh in fact it is much easier than I thought, thank you so much!

Comment: About the `Symbol#to_proc`, wonderful!